# Using a callback with $(location).attr()

Tags: jquery, attr

I am trying to trigger an event when a $(location).attr() is done. I have found many solutions to do this when the attr() is used to change a img src for example but not with $(location).attr().

You may ask why I want to do this?
In my application, I have a button to export data to an xml (using a php code in the background). But, this can take some time (several seconds!). So, I would like to display a tiny "Wait please during exportation" and then remove it once the xlsx is generated and the download started.

It that possible?

Comment: I suppose you are using ajax. So why not set a loading msg before the request and in success/complete callback remove this msg?

Comment: If it's the actual `window.location` you're changing, that would reload the page or start a download if the content disposition is set, if this is what you're trying to do, please explain it better. Also, it's usually not very good form to wrap the location object in jQuery ?

Comment: $(location).attr('href', "/" + module + "s/export/index?type=" + params.type + "... other parameters ..."); and then in my php I finish my controller with a $objWriter->save('php://output'); (objWriter is a PHPExcel object) that makes me download the file. The location does not reload the page

Comment: You should really be using `window.location.href = "/" + module + "s/export/index?type=" ... ` and not jQuery for that. There is no event to hook into when the Excel file is ready and the user receives the "download file" dialog, but there are ways to this with a little trickery and cookies, but it's somewhat complicated, heres a [**tutorial**](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#waitMessage").show();

$.post("processing.php", yourParameters)
    .then(function (data) {
      // handle success
    })
    .fail(function () {
      // handle server error
    })
    .always(function () {
      $("#waitMessage").hide();
    })
```